# How to convert `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>>>` to `Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>> `

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, casting

I tried:

```
endResult = tempResult.Where(x => x.Key.Equals(nameOfMyList))
                      .SelectMany(wert => wert as List<MyCustomClass>)
                      .Cast<Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>>>().ToDictionary(); //error "can not convert type"
```

`endResult` is `Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>>`.

`tempResult` is `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>>>`.

What's wrong here?

**UPDATED:**

Sorry, I wrote `endResult` is `Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>>`**and not** `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>>>`(updated it)

Actually I want to extract `Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>>`from`Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>>>`, kind of conversion, cast

Comment: Probably just a typo, but according to your topic I think your "endresult" -type should be Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't understand dictionaries. Check this example:

```
var foo = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>>>();
...
// Add some content to foo.
...

string nameOfMyList = ""; // Something that exists as a key in foo.

Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>> result = foo[nameOfMyList];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.SelectMany(wert => wert as List<MyCustomClass>)` returns an enumerator returning instances of `List<MyCustomClass>`. You are trying to cast that list to `Dictionary<string, List<MyCustomClass>>`. That is not possible, since those types are not exchangeable.

You have to make sure for yourself what conversion path you are looking for. It is possible to create a dictionary out of this, but you have to come up with a key yourself (which have to be unique):

```
.SelectMany(wert => wert as List<MyCustomClass>)
.ToDictionary( k => whatEverYourKeyIs
             , v => v /* this is the list */
             )
```